# Find all numbers between two numbers in Bash

Tags: bash

I have two variables like:

```
a=200
b=205
```

and want to find out all numbers between these two numbers (including. these specified numbers).

Comment: ...and the Oscar goes to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good tool is `seq` (as `ChronoTrigger` already stated), but this is not a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) internal function. Unfortunately the `{1..4}` notation is not working with variables. But there is a sideway:

```
a=200; b=205; eval "t=({$a..$b})"; echo ${t[*]}
```

Output:

```
200 201 202 203 204 205
```

The resulting array can be used in a for cycle later. `for i in ${t[*]};{ ...;}`. But better to use `for((...))` loop for that as `1_CR` stated.

**ADDED**

If it should be added some string as prefix or postfix to all elements then it is pretty easy to do:

```
echo ${t[*]/#/ab}
echo ${t[*]/%/cd}
```

Output:

```
ab200 ab201 ab202 ab203 ab204 ab205
200cd 201cd 202cd 203cd 204cd 205cd
```

**ADDED #2**

If fixed number of digits needed to be placed to the array this can be used

```
a=0; b=5; eval "t=({$a..$b})"; printf -v tt "%03d " ${t[*]}; t=($tt)
echo Array length: ${#t[*]}
echo ${t[*]}
```

Output:

```
Array length: 6
000 001 002 003 004 005
```

Comment: i think i will use this..

next step for me is adding a prefix to each like:

ab200 ab201 ab202 ..

Comment: @user2482699: Oh, it is pretty simple in `bash` if array is used. Solution added to my answer.

Comment: thank you a lot :) some numbers start with 00 (like 001), but eval cut these zeros is there an option to keep the beginning zeros?

Comment: i make a work around for my zero problem: ${#i} to find out, if i have to add zeros

Comment: @user2482699: I add some extension if You need the leading zeros.

Answer (score 10):

Check the `seq` instruction:

```
seq $a $b
```

Comment: While this is definitely the shortest solution, it's deemed a bit of a bash [anti-pattern](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices)

Comment: Yes, for loops, a built-in "for" is much better, but OP may be interested in something different.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [bash C-style for loop](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for). Note that a `$` is not needed before the `a` and `b`; this is characteristic of [bash arithmetic expressions.](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr)

```
for ((i=a; i<=b; ++i))                                
do
  echo $i
done
```

Alternately, to capture the numbers in an array

```
arr=()
for ((i=a; i<=b; ++i))                                
do
  arr+=($i)
done
echo "${arr[*]}"
```